# iPad: SplitViewController can detail view communicate with master view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

As title says - is this possible? I want my detail view to communicate with the master view, how would I go about doing that?

basically I want to set a property of the master view controller from my detail view.

Comment: Delegation is one way. using NSNotificationCenter is another.

Comment: Ok! I thought maybe there were a easier way. But Ill use the NotificationCenter